# PHP code will not execute unless there is an echo at a certain spot. Why is this?

Tags: php, mysql, echo

```
    $result=mysql_query($sql_info) or die("Error 1: ".mysql_error());
    $no= mysql_fetch_array($result);

    $groups_no = $no['number'];
    mysql_num_rows($result) or die("Error 2: ".mysql_error());    

//  echo "what's going on?"; if I uncomment this line then the echo below executes
    if(($this->user_group=="I am Talent") &&($groups_no==0)) {              
        header("Location: ".MAIN_URL.$this->groups_page);  
                    echo "what's going on?"; //THIS DOESN'T EXECUTE BY ITSELF...WHY NOT?? 
    } 
    if(mysql_result(mysql_query(sprintf("SELECT last_update FROM `users_profile` WHERE users_id=%d LIMIT 1",$this->id)),0)==0) {

        header("Location: ".MAIN_URL.$this->groups_page);
    }
        echo "what's going on?"; //won't execute unless the line above
```

Does anyone know why the above code wouldn't work unless there's an echo statement? I have confirmed through manual database checks that the first if statement should execute.

This should cause a redirection of the page to the link stored in the variable MAIN_URL.$this->groups_page (and this lack of redirection was the original issue). However, the header("Location: ...") part doesn't execute unless there is an echo either in the if statement or above the if statement. Why on earth would this be? I put an echo statement AFTER the header("Location: ".MAIN_URL.$this->groups_page); line in the first if-statement and it didn't execute. It would only execute if I had an echo statement before the header(...) line.

Comment: This is almost unreadable. Can you be more concise ?

Comment: Some variant of [headers already sent](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=headers%20already%20sent) and output_buffering enabled or not.

Comment: Wrap your `header()` calls as `exit(header("..."));` when they are supposed to be final.

Answer (score 2):

That echo really has no impact on the other echo.  What I suspect is going on is the second echo normally doesn't execute because the location redirects are sent to the browser first and thus the last echo is never displayed.

When you enable the first echo however, and then one of the location headers is sent to the browser, PHP should be issuing an error stating that output has already started (by the first echo).  In that case the second echo may be showing through, b/c the headers cannot be sent at that point.

@ldiqual ditto; I was in the middle of posting this when your answer came through ;)

Comment: Yes I definitely get the output error when the first echo is enabled. But that's not really the issue. The issue is that without an echo the header statement DOESN'T EXECUTE. When I have the first echo statement, the header statement will execute but otherwise it does nothing and redirects to the current page.

Comment: Also, I know solidly there is no whitespace, or problems with the includes.

Comment: @LJWiest-Berger are you **sure** the if condition is still succeeding when you have the echo disabled?  There are several things you could try, like logging something right before the header calls are made, calling header followed by an die where you don't wrap the header call in an if condition etc.  You could also sniff the traffic with something like tcpmon or firebug.  My guess is it's something w/ the conditions.  If you don't have the echo and call header, it should work.

Comment: I mean, it should right? There should be no reason a standard echo has an effect on an if-condition, correct? I'm not changing any variables or anything. It should be noted that the function doesn't seem to run to execution (any echo after the header call doesn't execute). This tells me that something is wrong with the header call but each time I output it it shows the proper page. This is beyond frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

Because you can't output anything before setting HTTP headers. You should normally get a PHP error like `Headers already sent by...`.
HTTP headers (in your case: `Location: ...`) are sent to the browser before the body.

According to [PHP: header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php):

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP. It is a very common error to read code with include(), or require(), functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.